# PHP holds only first data-userid from a row of 3

Tags: php, mysql

I face a problem with my PHP file. I have a table with 3 rows inside. I echo it with `<a>`, and I put `"data-userid"` in order to keep an information. However, when I click the `<a>` tags only from the first, I take the information that it held.

The code:

[image: Code]

The `#row['id']` is the information that I want to hold.

And the spot that I want to take the information:

[image: Spot]

When the 3 rows are shown only from the first `<a>`, I take the `id`, and the other 2 don't alert anything.

I would appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to give all of those elements a different `id`. That attribute must be unique in the document.

Comment: Consider binding the click event handler to a class instead.

Comment: *"I face a problem with my PHP file"* - well, it's a shame that nobody's going to rewrite that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the problem with your html which you are generating  under while loop.

Actually 'id' attribute for html elements is designed to maintain the uniqueness (like primary key in db).

Jquery in this case pick only the first matching element of the document.

Use class instead of id to achieve your desire functionality.